# How can I integrate SSH in HTML

Tags: html, ssh, minecraft

I want to go integrate the console of my Minecraft Server in an html page,(like in aternos.org) how can I do it?
I try to search on internet “integrate ssh in html” but I don’t find anything!

Comment: here is a list from [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/) page: [SSHy](https://github.com/stuicey/SSHy) , [WebSSH2](https://github.com/billchurch/WebSSH2) . This is most likely incomplete list but it can help you to get started and can give you extra keywords for further search ...

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to do it :

1. Use Minecraft panel manage such as [McSEmeGUI](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/77720/), [CraftControl](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/69036/), [Wizzer Panel](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/96997/) or [MC Dashboard](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/90534/)
2. Include aternos's console

I don't really know if it's possible, but maybe you can include it from their webpage to your own.

It seems to have at least one [unofficial API](https://github.com/hartontw/aternosAPI)

3. As Maxim Sagaydachny say's, you can use generic HTML SSH tool mentionned [here](https://xtermjs.org/)
4. Create your own tool. You just have to read `logs/latest.log`. Personnally, I already did something like that:

- A PHP script that read this file, and send all required line

```php
$count = 20; // amount of showed line
$dir = "/dir/to/logs/latest.log";
$file = file($dir);
if(file_exists($dir)){
    for ($i = max(0, count($file)-$count); $i < count($file); $i++) {
        echo $file[$i] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p style='color: red'>Could not find log file " . $dir . "</p>";
}
```

- In your webpage, just call this script

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { // if it's value request
        document.getElementById("my-id").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "link/to/log.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: No, I want to integrate a the console of minecraft Server hosted on my pc.

Comment: And I want that I can send command from php or html page.

Comment: Oh, not only log. Maybe one of mentionned software from first section can answer.

Comment: Ok now I try it

Comment: They’re all Minecraft plug-in! Otherwise there is a method for electron?

Comment: How can I open jar file whit php?

Comment: Open a jar file ? Wdym ?

Comment: else there is a method whit rcon?

Comment: open the Minecraft server jar file

Comment: MC panel user use rcon. And open mc jar is like read it or just start mc server ?

Comment: Start Minecraft server

Comment: You have to run a command which create a screen with java's command like that: `screen -dmS screenName java -jar spigot.jar`. To run command from php, you have to you exec or shell_exec

Comment: Ok, and how can i show the console on php page? (If you see grammatical error is because I’m Italian not English)